# Trying to pull certain data pieces of an LRS record, need catch-try assistance

Tags: tin-can-api

I have a script that is 90% complete and working. I'm using the older code for getting LRS statements. It is the one that uses tincan.js. I am trying to pull down and parse the following: Actor, verb, object, timestamp and the id **under contextActivities**. It is the last one that is giving me fits. Could you please look at my last catch/try statement and tell me where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<!--Parsing "resumed" statements-->
<html lang='en'> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset='UTF-8'> 
        <title>Get my Statements</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="build/tincan.js"></script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1>Get statements  101</h1> 
        <div id='response'></div>
        <script>
      var lrs;

try {
    lrs = new TinCan.LRS(
        {

            endpoint: "https://lrs.adlnet.gov/xapi/",
            username: "xapi-tools",
            password: "xapi-tools",
            allowFail: false
        }
    );
}
catch (ex) {
    console.log("Failed to setup LRS object: " + ex);
    // TODO: do something with error, can't communicate with LRS
}


//Pulls all of the resumed statements

lrs.queryStatements(
    {
        params: {
            verb: new TinCan.Verb(
                {
                    id: "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/completed"
                }
            ),
            since: "2016-01-05T08:34:16Z"
        },
        callback: function (err, sr) {
            if (err !== null) {
                console.log("Failed to query statements: " + err);
                // TODO: do something with error, didn't get statements
                return;
            }

            if (sr.more !== null) {
                // TODO: additional page(s) of statements should be fetched
            }

            var container =  document.getElementById('response');
            //container.innerHTML = (err !== null ? 'ERROR' : JSON.stringify(sr.statements));
            container.innerHTML = (err !== null ? 'ERROR' : parseMyData(sr));
        }
    }
);


parseMyData = function(result) {
            var statements = result.statements;
            var output = '';
            var name,verb,activity, timestamp, context;
            for(var i=0;i<statements.length;i++){
                // check the statement for a usable name value
                // (priority = actor.name, actor.mbox, actor.account.name)
                if(statements[i].actor.name != null && statements[i].actor.name != "") {
                    name = statements[i].actor.name
                }else if(statements[i].actor.mbox != null && statements[i].actor.mbox != "") {
                    name = statements[i].actor.mbox
                }else{
                    name = statements[i].actor.account.name
                }
                // check the statement for a usable verb value
                // (priority = verb.display['en-US'], verb.id)
                try{
                    verb = statements[i].verb.display['en-US'];
                }catch(e){
                    verb = statements[i].verb.id;
                }
                // check the activity for a usable value
                // (priority = definition.name['en-US'], id)
                try{
                    activity = statements[i].target.definition.name['en-US'];
                }catch(e){
                    activity = statements[i].target.id;
                }
                try{
                    timestamp = statements[i].timestamp;
                }catch(e){
                    timestamp = statements[i].timestamp;
                }

                try{
                    context = statements[i].target.contextActivities.other['id'];
                }catch(e){
                    context = statements[i].activity.other['id'];
                }

                output +=   name + ' - ' +
                            verb + ' - ' + 
                            activity + ' - ' +
                            timestamp + ' - ' +
                            context +
                            '<br>' 
            }
            return output;
}

        </script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a property that will never exist:

`statements[i].target.contextActivities`

The last portion of that will exist in `statements[i].context` when it exists, which is not always unless you know the statement ahead of time. Pretty much all of the properties should be checked for `null` before accessing them, doing so will allow you to remove your try/catch blocks. The property names themselves are very stable and the library explicitly assigns `null` values to known properties. Additionally the `other` property will hold an array of Activities (when it is populated) so you should access them by index, so `contextActivities.other[0].id` etc.

For the `target` property you should check that it is an instance of a particular class as it can contain multiple types of objects (so can `actor` but they effectively match). In general for this specific task you may also want to leverage the `toString` methods where possible, they do very similar work.

Comment: Thanks much. I will give it a try.